Similar voices datasets for Speaker Recognition/Verification
There are lots of audio datasets available to train speaker verification/recognition models to classify which speaker the voice belongs to. However, they mostly have noticeably different voices.
However, in the real world, there are people with similar voices, and people can try to imitate other peoples' voices. I want to know if there is an open dataset containing similar voices. For example, recordings of people mimicking the voice of celebrities. It doesn't have to be large, I just want to check how the models perform on such similar voices.
So far, I couldn't find one just by googling it. I find just the standard datasets used for speaker verification like VoxCeleb, People's Speech and so on. There are lots of datasets with lots of speakers, but none of them tell me if they have similar voices. When I google celeb voice mimicking, I'm led to AI-voice cloning models, but I'm looking for real human data. Is there such a dataset that has similar voices? I would prefer it if it was English dataset.
